# How can I use smtp to connect email to mail client

Tags: macos, ios, mail.app, email, smtp

Right so we have set up a mail server for our company that does not use imap nor pop at the moment, it is based on smtp port 25 and I can't figure out how to link it with my mail client as it always asks for imap or pop :/

Comment: So you're email server only facilitates sending mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As forcer obliquely mentioned SMTP is for *sending* mail. And one of the most popular programs to do that is called "Sendmail." Not that you need to know that, but hey...

Anyway to be able to send and receive email you need both an SMTP server *and* an **incoming** mail server that speaks either POP or IMAP. I won't go into Exchange here as it is Microsoft's own take on IMAP.

Often times the sending and receiving servers are the same. At work mine is mail.domain.local. It sounds like you may have plugged in the same server (or IP address) for sending email into the receiving (POP/IMAP) mail location in your mail.app. If it didn't work, you will have to bug your IT folks for the POP/IMAP address too.

Comment: Well, mail server is based on this software https://github.com/MLstate/PEPS at the moment, as far as I understood it is all through smtp

Comment: @IlyaKnaup No, SMTP is only for sending email. From glancing through the documentation, I get the impression that PEPS offers webmail only. It's curious that they offer an SMTP server though, and no instructions on how to set up an example client, as you'd need to set up the client-side encryption (otherwise it wouldn't be end-to-end). The documentation seems very poor to me.